# The rank problem of matrices produced by vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\alpha = [\alpha_1 \dots \alpha_N]^T$, $\beta = [\beta_1 \dots \beta_N]^T$ and $\gamma = [\gamma_1 \dots \gamma_N]^T$. These vectors are linearly independent. It should be easy to point out that rank($\alpha\alpha^H + \beta\beta^H + \gamma\gamma^H$) = 3 where H means conjugate transpose. My Matlab simulation finds out that rank($\alpha\beta^H + \beta\alpha^H+ \beta\gamma^H + \gamma\beta^H + \alpha\gamma^H + \gamma\alpha^H$) = 3. Could anybody proves this or point some references for this question? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that for square matrices $F,G$ we have that  $F$ is 1--1 and onto implies $\mathrm{rk} (FG)=\mathrm{rk} (G) = \mathrm{rk} (GF)$.

Now let $e_1,\dots, e_N$ be the standard basis of our $N$ dimensional space. Choose $S$ to be invertible sending $e_1,e_2,e_3$ to $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Then your expression is just $S M S^H$ where $M=e_1 e_2^H +e_2 e_1^H + \dots$. It is easy to see that $M$ has zero entries everywhere except in the top left $3\times 3$ block, where it is $0$ on the diagonal and $1$ off the diagonal.

Hence $\mathrm{rk}(M)=3$ by inspection and so by the first remark the rank of your matrix is also $3$.